# C++ / Concatenate std::string and wchar* to wchar*

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to concatenate a `std::string` and `WCHAR*` and the result should be in `WCHAR*`.

I tried the following code

```
size_t needed = ::mbstowcs(NULL,&input[0],input.length());
std::wstring output;
output.resize(needed);
::mbstowcs(&output[0],&input[0],input.length());
const wchar_t wchar1 = output.c_str();
const wchar_t * ptr=wcsncat( wchar1, L" program", 3 );
```

I got following errors

> error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
>
> error C2664: 'wcsncat' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const wchar_t *' to 'wchar_t*'

Comment: That's nice. Did you try anything?

Comment: You're not welcome. Try something, show us some effort or a usage example, and then edit your question. :3c

Comment: Yes ma..ha..aster (*squeeking sound*)... maste... ma.. ma..

Comment: `output.c_str()` returns a `const wchar_t *` (note the asterisk). You must declare the type of `wchar1` accordingly. Furthermore, for the result of `wcsncat` you need a `wchar_t *` without const. You can't use `output.c_str()` there.

Answer (score 4):

If you call [`string.c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to get at the raw buffer, it will return a const pointer to indicate that you shouldn't try to change the buffer.  And definitely you shouldn't try to concatenate anything to it.  Use a second string class instance and let the runtime do most of the work for you.

```
std::string input; // initialized elsewhere
std::wstring output;

output = std::wstring(input.begin(), input.end());
output = output + std::wstring(L" program"); // or output += L" program";
const wchar_t *ptr = output.c_str();
```

Also remember this. Once "output" goes out of scope and destructs, "ptr" will be invalid.

Comment: +1 for `std::wstring(L" program"); // or output += L" program";` (I wasn't sure if the `operator+` returns a `std::wstring` or not since it's a non-member function, unlike `operator+=`.)

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says

> wchar_t * wcsncat ( wchar_t * destination, wchar_t * source, size_t num );
>   Appends the first num wide characters of source to destination, plus a terminating null wide character.
>   destination is returned.
>   (Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcsncat/)

You cannot pass your const wchar1 as destination, because the function will modifiy this and then return it. So you better

- allocate a wchar array of the appropriate size
- copy your string into it
- call wcsncat with your newley allocated wchar array as destination.

However, I wonder if you cannot just use string to do your operations, which is more the C++ way to do it. (Arrays are C-style)